# Enforce string constructor parameter

Tags: php, oop

Is this the accepted way to enforce a string constructor parameter in php:

```
public function __construct($myParameter)
{
    if (! is_string($myParameter)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('My parameter must be a string');
    }

    $this->myParameter = $myParameter;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **PHP** (prior to version 7) does not allow to **typehint** any simple types (int, string, boolean, float), but only arrays, classes and interfaces, such typecheck needs to be done manually. PHP provides a family of **is_*** functions that can help with checking the type of a variable: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.var.php

Answering your question, yes, what you provided is rather common way of enforcing type of function's arguments.